# Define loop iMacros in batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, imacros

I want to create an art of a batch file, where you can set a variable loop, and the iMacros run variable times.

Anybody has an idea how to write this on a batch file? I already know how to start a iMacro over a batch, but not how to make it loop and set the variable, and couldn't find it anywhere on the net.

Comment: Perhaps if you show us how to start a iMacro in a batch file and the exact value you want to "set in the variable" (you should elaborate on this point) and how to "loop" on it, we could help you. Please, modify your question; do not put additional information as a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this in your iMacros script at the beginning:

```
SET !LOOP -9999999
```

And create a batch file with this:

```
start firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=MYIMACROSFILE.iim
```

There you go

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set for each time the cmd is running the times of loop for the specific iMacros:

```
@echo off
echo Running All LOOP SCENARIOS
set BATCH_FILE_DIR=%~dp0
set loopNumber=0
set /P max="Enter Max Loop Number: "
:start
if %loopNumber%==%max% goto end
echo Loop Number %loopNumber%
set /a loopNumber +=1
echo ---------------------------------------------
echo LOOP SCENARIOS
echo ---------------------------------------------
cmd /C %BATCH_FILE_DIR%\alm1.iim
cmd /C %BATCH_FILE_DIR%\dls.iim
goto start
:end
echo Maximum Loop Number reached = %max% 
pause
```